# How to define a specific layout onclick function globally for multiple activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I need to define a layout for multiple activities in android and from the UI part, it is successful. But to code those elements to perform on each click listeners, I need to define it in all the java pages I use.

Can we globally define this in a java page and include it in the required pages?

```
menuButton = findViewById(R.id.menuButton);

menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: depends on your code. If you want your menu to be in all the activities, it might be easier to extend all your activities from a common activity, and add your menu item. Otherwise, I suggest you make a public static class to store your onclick function and ppas your context to that. Also, dont use `getApplicationContext( )` when you dont need it. Use activity context

Comment: @ColonD How can I use `findViewById(R.id.purchase_order)` in a public static class? If possible, can you share an example!

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No.

You can create a `BaseActivity` which has the common logic that has to be executed for each button click.

But you need to implement the listener for the button on specific activity, since life cycle of each activity is independent of other activity.

To make the code readable better (avoiding `implementing listener`/`setOnclickListener`), you can use [ButterKinfe](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife), and create a method for `OnClick()` annotation, and call the method in `BaseActivity`.

Comment: So, need to define the listener in the JAVA activity itself!

Comment: Yes. Activity should have visibility to the component to listen to.

Answer (score -1):

What you essentially want to do is call the `findViewById()`, which can only be called if you have a reference to a `Context` variable. You should use your `Activity` `Context`, hence you pass `this` to the static function, which can then access all methods accessible via `Context` .

```
public class ExampleActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MenuUtils.setListener(this);
    }
}
```

Define the static class like this:

```
public static class MenuUtils{

  public static void setListener(Context context){
        menuButton = context.findViewById(R.id.menuButton);
        menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
          // do stuff
        }
    });

  }
}
```

What you should be careful about is that any `Activity` you pass to this function should have a `menuButton` in it's layout, otherwise you run the risk of getting a `NullPointerException`, which is when `findViewById()` cannot find `menuButton`.